# Why is fct_lump from forcats not working on my data?

Tags: r, forcats

I've been off R for a few months, so that might have had some consequences.

I found this dataset on the internet. I treated it some, so I'll just `dput()` it here, but it originally came from https://ourworldindata.org/terrorism.

```
> dput(ter)
structure(list(region = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", 
"Angola", "Argentina", "Australasia & Oceania", "Australia", 
"Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Belgium", 
"Brazil", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Central African Republic", 
"Central America & Caribbean", "Central Asia", "Chad", "Chile", 
"China", "Colombia", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Czech Republic", "Democratic Republic of the Congo", 
"Djibouti", "Dominican Republic", "East Asia", "Eastern Europe", 
"Ecuador", "Egypt", "Ethiopia", "Finland", "France", "Gabon", 
"Georgia", "Germany", "Greece", "Honduras", "India", "Indonesia", 
"Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Jordan", 
"Kenya", "Kosovo", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos", "Latvia", "Lebanon", 
"Liberia", "Libya", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", 
"Malta", "Mexico", "Middle East & North Africa", "Mozambique", 
"Myanmar", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Niger", "Nigeria", "North America", 
"Macedonia", "Norway", "Pakistan", "Palestine", "Papua New Guinea", 
"Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Russia", "Rwanda", 
"Saudi Arabia", "Serbia", "Sierra Leone", "Somalia", "South Africa", 
"South America", "South Asia", "South Sudan", "Southeast Asia", 
"Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Sudan", "Sweden", 
"Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Tunisia", 
"Turkey", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "UK", "USA", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", 
"Western Europe", "World", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), Code = c("AFG", 
"ALB", "DZA", "AGO", "ARG", NA, "AUS", "AUT", "AZE", "BHR", "BGD", 
"BEL", "BRA", "BFA", "BDI", "CMR", "CAN", "CAF", NA, NA, "TCD", 
"CHL", "CHN", "COL", "CIV", "CZE", "COD", "DJI", "DOM", NA, NA, 
"ECU", "EGY", "ETH", "FIN", "FRA", "GAB", "GEO", "DEU", "GRC", 
"HND", "IND", "IDN", "IRN", "IRQ", "IRL", "ISR", "ITA", "JAM", 
"JOR", "KEN", "OWID_KOS", "KGZ", "LAO", "LVA", "LBN", "LBR", 
"LBY", "MWI", "MYS", "MDV", "MLI", "MLT", "MEX", NA, "MOZ", "MMR", 
"NPL", "NLD", "NER", "NGA", NA, "MKD", "NOR", "PAK", "PSE", "PNG", 
"PRY", "PER", "PHL", "POL", "RUS", "RWA", "SAU", "SRB", "SLE", 
"SOM", "ZAF", NA, NA, "SSD", NA, "ESP", "LKA", NA, "SDN", "SWE", 
"SYR", "TWN", "TJK", "TZA", "THA", "TUN", "TUR", "UGA", "UKR", 
"GBR", "USA", "VEN", "VNM", NA, "OWID_WRL", "YEM", "ZMB", "ZWE"
), Year = c(2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017), `Terrorism fatalities (GTD, 2018)` = c(6092, 
0, 12, 7, 0, 4, 4, 2, 5, 6, 25, 2, 0, 53, 20, 228, 6, 601, 4, 
6, 62, 0, 16, 84, 3, 0, 596, 0, 2, 16, 101, 0, 877, 67, 2, 7, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 465, 20, 39, 6476, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 126, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 17, 0, 289, 0, 4, 1, 361, 1, 23, 10819, 22, 218, 4, 0, 148, 
1805, 124, 0, 0, 1076, 50, 0, 4, 8, 496, 0, 61, 2, 31, 0, 0, 
1912, 21, 101, 7664, 581, 811, 21, 1, 6712, 82, 5, 2026, 0, 1, 
8, 72, 5, 222, 7, 40, 42, 95, 5, 0, 83, 26445, 762, 0, 0)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -115L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Entity = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Code = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `Terrorism fatalities (GTD, 2018)` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

I tried many things, always shrinking the important code. In the end, I used the example code from `vignette("forcats")` (I hae `tidyverse` loaded), and tried it with different datasets:

```
starwars %>%
  mutate(skin_color = fct_lump(skin_color, n = 5)) %>%
  count(skin_color, sort = TRUE)
  
ter %>%
  mutate(hair = fct_lump(region, n = 5)) %>%
  count(hair, sort = TRUE)

gss_cat %>%
  mutate(relig = fct_lump(relig, n = 5)) %>%
  count(relig, sort = TRUE)
```

It works as expected with both `starwars` and `gss_cat`, but not with `ter` (my data):

```
> ter %>%
+   mutate(hair = fct_lump(region, n = 5)) %>%
+   count(hair, sort = TRUE)
# A tibble: 115 x 2
   hair                      n
   <fct>                 <int>
 1 Afghanistan               1
 2 Albania                   1
 3 Algeria                   1
 4 Angola                    1
 5 Argentina                 1
 6 Australasia & Oceania     1
 7 Australia                 1
 8 Austria                   1
 9 Azerbaijan                1
10 Bahrain                   1
# … with 105 more rows
```

Why is this happening? Why isn't `fct_lump()` working here?

Comment: You only have one entry for each country. `fct_lump` will lump together the `n` least frequent instances, but if they all have the same frequency, what is it you are expecting `fct_lump` to do?

Comment: Oh, true... Oops

Comment: Which function can I use so that it lumps according to `Terrorism fatalities (GTD, 2018)` (another column)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you wish to lump together regions with less than 5 fatalities into an "other" category. This is straightforward in base R

```r
ter$region <- as.character(ter$region)
ter$region[which(ter$`Terrorism fatalities (GTD, 2018)` < 5)] <- "Other"
ter$region <- factor(ter$region)
```

If you wanted, you could then use `forcats` to relevel according to the fatality level:

```r
ter$region <- fct_reorder(ter$region, ter$`Terrorism fatalities (GTD, 2018)`)

ggplot(ter, aes(region, `Terrorism fatalities (GTD, 2018)`)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Or if you run the above code but lump together all regions with a fatality of less than 500, you get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! But do you know if there's a way to do this: `ter$region[which(ter$\`Terrorism fatalities (GTD, 2018)\` < 5)] <- "Other"` inside a pipeline? I have one already, and this would be right in the middle of it...

Comment: I thought on using `mutate`, but that code only applies to specific rows, so I don't know...

Comment: `mutate(region = ifelse('Terrorism fatalities (GTD, 2018)' < 5, "Other", region))` - note I had to change the backticks to apostrophes to get this to work in a comment. Another danger of having illegal column names. Why not change this column name to `fatalities` - it would make your life easier and your code more readable!